# How to remove Preview.app on-screen navigation toolbar?

Tags: macos, preview, fullscreen

When I open a picture in fullscreen, it has an overlay like this:
[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to permanently disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going into 'Slide show' not full screen.

This maybe because you are using the wrong shortcut keys.

For Slide show:

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

For full screen:

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

---

[image]

Comment: This solution is not working as in BigSur. If you go into Fullscreen with the mentioned keys, the annoying bar is still there. Hope next updates allow to eliminate it.